# How to turn off the Touchpad so it STAYS off!

Tags: touchpad

Ver 14.04

In System Settings -> Mouse & Touchpad, I set "Touchpad" to OFF. This works fine until I reboot the computer.... then the "Touchpad" is back ON. Is it possible to turn it off and have it stay off??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a toggle touchpad key that disables/enables the hardware. In my laptop it's Fn+F3 combination. You might like to use that feature. It's handy.

Answer (score 2):

There are two possibilities.

1. In you BIOS settings, you may have an option to disable the touchpad, during system POST,(when you hit the power on button) immediately hold down F2 or F8 or F12 whatever is the key defined by your laptop manufacturer.  If the option exists it will turn it off until you enable the device in the BIOS setup.
2. Install Touchpad Indicator, we use it on the wife's Lenovo which has no BIOS option to disable the touchpad in the BIOS. You can install from command line.

> ```
> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:atareao/atareao
>
> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get install touchpad-indicator
> ```

I hope one of these will solve your issue.